# How to set Neo4J config keys in gremlin-scala?

Tags: apache, scala, neo4j, gremlin, gremlin-server

When running a Neo4J database server standalone (on Ubuntu 14.04), configuration [options](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/) are [set](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/#file-locations) for the global installation in `etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` or possibly `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf`.

However, when instantiating a Neo4j database from Java or Scala using Apache's `Neo4jGraph` class (`org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph`), there is no global installation, and the constructor does not ([as far as I can tell](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/neo4j-gremlin/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/neo4j/structure/Neo4jGraph.java)) look for any configuration files.

In particular, when running the test suite for my application, I end up with many simultaneous instances of `Neo4jGraph`, which ends up throwing a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` because all of these instances are trying to communicate over a small range of ports for online backup, which I don't actually need. These channels are set with config options `dbms.backup.address` (default value: `127.0.0.1:6362-6372`) and `dbms.backup.enabled` (default value: `true`).

My problem would be solved by setting `dbms.backup.enabled` to `false`, or expanding the port range.

Things that have not worked:

- Creating `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` containing the line `dbms.backup.enabled=false`.
- Creating the same file in my project's `src/main/resources` directory.
- Creating the same file in `src/main/resources/neo4j`.
- Manually setting the configuration property inside the Scala code:

`val db = new Neo4jGraph(dataDirectory)
db.configuration.addProperty("dbms.backup.enabled",false)`

- or

`db.configuration.addProperty("neo4j.conf.dbms.backup.enabled",false)`

- or

`db.configuration.addProperty("gremlin.neo4j.conf.dbms.backup.enabled",false)`

How should I go about setting this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating `db.configuration` after the database connection had already been opened was definitely futile.

[stephen mallette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831717/stephen-mallette)'s answer was on the right track, but this particular configuration doesn't appear to pass through in the way his linked example does. There is a naming mismatch between the configuration keys expected in `neo4j.conf` and those expected in `org.neo4j.backup.OnlineBackupKernelExtension`. Instead of `dbms.backup.address` and `dbms.backup.enabled`, that class looks for config keys `online_backup_server` and `online_backup_enabled`.

I was not able to get these keys passed down to the underlying `Neo4jGraphAPI` instance correctly. What I had to do, instead, was the following:

```
import org.neo4j.tinkerpop.api.impl.Neo4jFactoryImpl
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val factory = new Neo4jFactoryImpl()
val config = Map(
    "online_backup_enabled" -> "true",
    "online_backup_server" -> "0.0.0.0:6350-6359"
).asJava
val db = Neo4jGraph.open(factory.newGraphDatabase(dataDirectory,config))
```

With this initialization, the instance correctly listened for backups on port 6350; changing `"true"` to `"false"` disabled backup listening.

Answer (score 0):

`Neo4jGraph` configuration through TinkerPop is accomplished by a pass-through of configuration keys. In TinkerPop 3.x, that would mean that all Neo4j keys prefixed with `gremlin.neo4j.conf` that are provided via `Configuration` object to `Neo4jGraph.open()` or `GraphFactory.open()` will be passed down directly to the Neo4j instance. You can see examples of this [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/reference/#_high_availability_configuration) in the TinkerPop documentation on high availability configuration.

In TinkerPop 2.x, the same approach was taken however the key prefix was instead `blueprints.neo4j.conf.*` as discussed [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Neo4j-Implementation#graphfactory-settings).

Comment: Does setting Configuration key `gremlin.neo4j.conf.dbms.backup.address` to, say, `0.0.0.0:6350-6359` produce an instance listening on that port range? For me it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Using Neo4j 3.0.0 the following disables port listening for me (Java code)

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph;

BaseConfiguration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
conf.setProperty(Neo4jGraph.CONFIG_DIRECTORY, "/path/to/db");
conf.setProperty(Neo4jGraph.CONFIG_CONF + "." + "dbms.backup.enabled", "false");
graph = Neo4jGraph.open(config);
```